# Lentitud en Script SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo el siguiente Script, lo explicare por partes

primero guardo información de unas tarjetas en una tabla temporal

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#InformacionClientesTarjetas') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #InformacionClientesTarjetas;

SELECT 
 ict.CuentaId
,ict.CodigoCliente
,ict.Saldo
INTO #InformacionClientesTarjetas
FROM OTROSERVER.OTRABASE.InformacionTarjetas ict
WHERE ict.Fecha = '2023-12-31'
```

esto porque esta data se encuentra en un servidor aparte y pues para que no haga muy lenta la consulta mediante el linked server , solo traigo la información que necesito a mi servidor local,  por eso coloque los nombres de OTROSERVER.OTRABASE

Luego guardo en otra tabla temporal otra información que se encuentra en otro servidor, pero en esta ocasión lo hago mediante un OPENQUERY

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#CCMST') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CCMST;

SELECT * 
INTO #CCMST
FROM OPENQUERY ( LINKED,'
SELECT
 CL.CodigoCliente
,CL.NombreCliente
,CL.IdentificacionCliente
,CL.Cuenta
FROM CLIENTES CL
' )
```

Hasta acá todo bien, ambas tablas se generan en aproximadamente 1 minuto ambas, la primera contiene 64,643 registros y la segunda alrededor de 211,694 registros

el problema viene cuando quiero unirlas, al unirlas de esta forma

```
SELECT
t.CuentaId
,t.Saldo
,c.NombreCliente
,c.IdentidadCliente
FROM #InformacionClientesTarjetas t

OUTER APPLY(
SELECT TOP 1 C.NombreCliente, C.CodigoCliente, C.IdentidadCliente
FROM #CCMST C
WHERE C.Cuenta = t.CuentaId
)c
```

La consulta me genera la informacion pero tarda demasiado, tarda alrededor de 12 minutos, he probado colocando los siguientes indices a las 2 tablas temporales

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Cuenta1 ON #InformacionClientesTarjetas (CuentaId)
CREATE INDEX idx_Cuenta2 ON #CCMST(Cuenta)
```

pero siempre obtengo el mismo resultado, he ejecutado el plan de ejecucion y obtengo el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que la consulta no tarde tanto tiempo, no se si estaré creando mal los indices , si alguien me ayuda porfavor

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por teoria (no lo puedo asegurar en la practica) si son tablas temporales, agregar los indices no tendria mucho sentido porque hay que recrearlos cada vez que llenas las tablas... eso pasaria igual con cualquier tipo de tablas. Porque haces un OUTER?

Comment: Por que no pruebas algo más clásico como `SELECT t.CuentaId, t.Saldo, c.NombreCliente, c.IdentidadCliente FROM #InformacionClientesTarjetas t LEFT JOIN #CCMST c on c.Cuenta = t.CuentaId` ?

Comment: Por otro lado `CuentaId`  y `Cuenta`  tiene el mismo tipo de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios detalles sencillos que pueden hacer una gran diferencia.

En primer lugar, recomiendo crear las tablas temporales desde antes de cargar los datos y asignar los tipos de datos adecuados.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#InformacionClientesTarjetas') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #InformacionClientesTarjetas;

CREATE TABLE #InformacionClientesTarjetas(
    CuentaId    int,
    CodigoCliente   varchar(16),--Asumo que es un código alfanumérico
    Saldo           float
);

IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#CCMST') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CCMST;

CREATE TABLE #CCMST(
    CodigoCliente    varchar(16),
    NombreCliente    varchar(200),
    IdentidadCliente int,
    Cuenta           int
);
```

Después, aun antes de cargar los datos, crear los índices como clustered para que contengan toda la información necesaria y solo escribir la información una vez. Los índices nonclustered (como los que creaste) duplican la información, mientras que los clustered son escencialmente la tabla.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_Cuenta1 ON #InformacionClientesTarjetas (CuentaId);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_Cuenta2 ON #CCMST(Cuenta)
```

También podrías tratar de eliminar duplicados desde la carga de información.

```
INSERT INTO #CCMST
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM OPENQUERY ( LINKED,'
    SELECT
         CL.CodigoCliente
        ,CL.NombreCliente
        ,CL.IdentificacionCliente
        ,CL.Cuenta
    FROM CLIENTES CL' );
```

Por último, si aun tienes cuentas duplicadas, en vez de usar APPLY para obtener el primer valor de cada fila y hacer consultas anidadas, puedes asignar los números desde antes para hacerlo más eficiente. Esto lo logras con un CTE (también podría ser una subconsulta como tabla derivada) y la función ROW_NUMBER().

```
WITH cteCCMST AS(
    SELECT CodigoCliente
        ,NombreCliente
        ,IdentidadCliente
        ,Cuenta
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Cuenta ORDER BY( CodigoCliente)) rn
    FROM #CCMST
)
SELECT
    t.CuentaId
    ,t.Saldo
    ,c.NombreCliente
    ,c.IdentidadCliente
FROM #InformacionClientesTarjetas t
LEFT JOIN cteCCMST C ON C.Cuenta = t.CuentaId
WHERE c.rn = 1;

-- Opción alterna
SELECT
    t.CuentaId
    ,t.Saldo
    ,c.NombreCliente
    ,c.IdentidadCliente
FROM #InformacionClientesTarjetas t
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT CodigoCliente
                ,NombreCliente
                ,IdentidadCliente
                ,Cuenta
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Cuenta ORDER BY( CodigoCliente)) rn
            FROM #CCMST
        ) C ON C.Cuenta = t.CuentaId
WHERE c.rn = 1;
```